# I can't use char in function

Tags: c++

```
bool potezn(int x,int y,int k,char c,char ram1[][100],bool segfault,int n,int m)
{
    segfault=true;
    if(c=='U' && x>=k){x=x-k;segfault=false;}
    if(c=='D' && x+k<n){x=x+k;segfault=false;}
    if(c=='L' && y>=k){y=y-k;segfault=false;}
    if(c=='R' && y+k<m){y=y+k;segfault=false;}
    if(ram1[x][y]=='.')ram1[x][y]='N';//zauzima polozaj ukoliko moze
    return segfault;
}

segfault=potezn(x,y,q,c,ram,segfault,n,m);
```

This is my code,and when i run it,i keep getting error

> D:\dev\Dev-Cpp\segfault2.cpp
>
> cannot convert `char (*)[((unsigned int)((int)m))]` to `char (*)[100]` for argument `5` to `bool potezn(int, int, int, char, char (*)[100], bool, int, int)`

Help please,
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is `ram` declared? Looks like you are trying to pass a variable-length array (VLA) for a parameter that expects a regular, fixed length array. Note also that VLA is not valid C++; they are a C-only feature that GCC supports in C++ as an extension.

Comment: As you're using C++, try to change ram1 to `std::vector` otherwise, use a `char**`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that compile error is because the type of `ram` that you are trying to call the function `potezn` with is not the type `potezn` wants.

Take a careful look at `ram`.

Its type must be `char*[100]`, not `char(*)[((unsigned int)((int)m)]]`.

You can either declare `ram`'s length explicitly, or change `char ram1[][100]` to `char * ram1.` 
(Also consider using `std::vector.` `std::vector` is an array that manages its length automatically for you.)

```
void Foo(char ram[][100]);
void Bar(char * ram); // Treat the ram as one long chunk array.

int main()
{
    char ram[5][100];
    char ram_error[5][5];

    Foo(ram); // Ok.
    Foo(ram_error); // Error.

    Bar(reinterpret_cast<char *>(ram_error)); // Ok. Not recommended.

    return 0;
}
```